# Bootstrap alert in a fixed floating div at the top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web application which uses Bootstrap (2.3.2 - corporate policy, we cannot upgrade to 3.0 without lots of testing across several web applications). We have several long pages within this application that require validation of forms and tables - however due to practical and aesthetic reasons we need to have an alert message appear as a floating div at the top of the page.

This will be a fixed floating div, that can be shown and hidden using javascript as and when needed. This part works and I can control this div, whenever I need to flash some information to the user or some error takes place.

The layout is like so:

```
<div id="message">
    <div id="inner-message" class="alert alert-error">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        test error message
    </div>
</div>
```

The styling is below:

```
#message {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#inner-message {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The #message div behaves all well and good, but when I try and add some padding to the #message div (to try and get some space between the edge of the page and the div i.e. padding: 5px), the div only gets padding on the left and top and the rest of the div is pushed out too far to the right of the page (hiding part of the 'x' inside the bootstrap alert).

Has anyone experienced this before? It seems like a simple enough issue, so am I overlooking something?

Comment: Attempted that @Dan, but same behaviour when I added a margin to that div, it gets a margin on the top and left - pushing out the rest of the div a few pixels out of the right hand side of the page. Its now is an inner div, so I could add padding to the outer div, but still behaving the same.

Comment: I deleted my comment b/c I realized that as I started looking at it a bit more

Comment: Use `class="fixed-top"` provided by Bootstrap

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just wrap your inner message inside a div on which you apply your padding : http://jsfiddle.net/Ez9C4/

```
<div id="message">
    <div style="padding: 5px;">
        <div id="inner-message" class="alert alert-error">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            test error message
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should add `z-index: 999;` in order to set the alerts in front of any element.

Comment: They changed "alert-error" to "alert-danger" in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 65):

If you want an alert that is fixed to the top and you are using bootstrap navbar  navbar-fixed-top the following style class will overlay they alert on top of the nav:

```
.alert-fixed {
    position:fixed; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9999; 
    border-radius:0px
}
```

This worked well for me to provide alerts even when the user is scrolled down in the page.

Comment: Is there a way to use this but not cover the fixed navbar when the user scrolls to the top of the page?

Comment: I use your example but I can't click on my navbar which is also fixed. Did you solve it @Harry?

Comment: @AlexVentura I don't think I did in the end, I had to make a choice between having it fixed on scroll or having it above the navbar but not fixed, so I went with the latter. Thinking about it though, there must be a JS way to add e.g. a `margin-top` of the height of the alert to the body when the alert is on. If I get a chance to give this a go I'll get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @Harry as you mention I have solved this I used `margin-top` with value equals to my navbar height. And now it works like a charm, both my fixed navbar and my fixed alerts.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest approach would be to use any of these class utilities that Bootstrap provides:

#### Bootstrap 5

```html
<div class="position-static">...</div>
<div class="position-relative">...</div>
<div class="position-absolute">...</div>
<div class="position-fixed">...</div>
<div class="position-sticky">...</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/

#### Bootstrap 4

```html
<div class="position-static">...</div>
<div class="position-relative">...</div>
<div class="position-absolute">...</div>
<div class="position-fixed">...</div>
<div class="position-sticky">...</div>

<!-- Deprecated classnames -->
<div class="fixed-top">...</div>
<div class="fixed-bottom">...</div>
<div class="sticky-top">...</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is that you need to wrap your `div` in a container and/or row.

This should achieve a similar look as what you are looking for:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="error-container">
         <div class="span12">  
             <div class="alert alert-error">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                 test error message
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#error-container {
     margin-top:10px;
     position: fixed;
}
```

[**Bootply demo**](http://www.bootply.com/EduJ1RzWHh)

Comment: I just attempted your code, with some changes to the css. position: fixed; margin:10px; width: 100%; - same issue.

Comment: I updated it...try now, and I don't think you need to add any padding here.

Comment: Was trying to keep it native with bootstrap styling and minimal css changes, but I agree :)

Answer (score 3):

Others are suggesting a wrapping `div` but you should be able to do this without adding complexity to your html...

check this out:

```css
#message {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Does this work, when position:fixed for #message? I cant seem to get it to work, I need to have the message div floating on top of the page at all times, as the user may have scrolled down the page.

Comment: @Husman works for me http://www.bootply.com/4pj9zm88a8
 Which browser are you on?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this class : `class="sticky-top alert alert-dismissible"`