# How to show alert in UI bootstrap when user is at different point in page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular for a web app. I used Angular UI bootstrap to show an alert in my page as response to some action, say a button click. However, I placed this alert div at beginning of the page. My page is long. So when I'm some where at the middle of the page and an alert happens, the user will not know the alert happened because it is at beginning of the page. I want to scroll page automatically to alert area when it happens. How to do this ?

Some what related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24203856/2182674, but its not looking quite good to show at fixed place in the page. That is overlaying page content and not good for my case.

Alert content is set by a controller in angular. So using href anchor for button won't work.

Comment: I've used this..http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/  instead of $anchorScroll.  It adds smooth scroll behavior which is simply less jarring for the user.  That said, I would use a modal instead of an alert.  From a UX perspective it will be way better than taking control and scrolling away from the point in the content where the user is forcing them to 'find their place' again (especially on a mobile device!).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple anchor html element :

```
<a id="myalert">Alerte</a>
...
<a href="#myalert">Go to the alert</a>
```

Comment: Basically, on click of a button, a controller in Angular will do some action and return a response. The response is shown in UI bootstrap alert.

Answer (score 1):

When triggering the action you can scroll to the alert element using something like this:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    /* trigger UI bootstrap alert */
    /* ... */

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#alertElementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Is this jquery ? I'm using angular. For now I used $window.scrollTo(0, 0);, it doesn't give nice scroll animiation though.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use jQuery ? It's pretty much a standard nowadays, even this very site uses it.

Comment: Since my application is running on Angular, I don't want to mix both.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's your choice. But as stated in https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq, Angular plays nicely with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Angular can [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) to an element:

```
angular.module('anchorScrollExample', [])
.controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
  function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
      // set the location.hash to the id of
      // the element you wish to scroll to.
      $location.hash('bottom');

      // call $anchorScroll()
      $anchorScroll();
    };
  }]);
```